# Colour of lightning

Tags: visible-light, spectroscopy, lightning

I thought the excitation of nitrogen leads to blue lightning but I am seeing a lot of yellow lightning on the Internet https://youtu.be/nbG5g5Elq2M
https://youtu.be/MRQUvjMY8wI
What is the explanation?

Comment: Is there more neon in the air these days? https://youtu.be/oFdZNwmy8oY

Comment: There are some yellow emission spectrum lines for nitrogen https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Nitrogen_Spectra.jpg how do they get these to dominate?

Comment: Rydberg atoms, generated by low-frequency lightnings, emit at red to orange color and can give the lightning a yellowish to greenish tint

Comment: you can check out this link:(though roughly, but you can have an idea in someway): https://www.wfmz.com/news/what-color-is-lightning/article_b65b63c8-7cd1-56d0-b909-88ac635edc8b.html#:~:text=Yellow%20or%20orange%20lightning%20occurs,of%20moisture%20in%20the%20air.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolaser I think is this Laser induced Rydberg atoms. People are saying even the thunder sound is different/ non existent

Comment: youtu.be/21aR8RezdQ8 AC voltage of microwave transformer also causes yellow. Sodium in the metal or same as above?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://uvhero.com/what-color-is-lightning/, "Yellow lightning is uncommon; however, they tend to be cooler than the blue, lilac and white. They’re caused to due to a high concentration of dust in the air. And is an indication of a dry thunderstorm with low-precipitation." I cannot be sure though if this source is reliable.